# laravel 5.7 whereNull

Tags: laravel, query-builder, laravel-5.7, laravel-query-builder

I want to get data from database where the value of specific column are null, i've searched from laravel doc query builder said use whereNull and i did but i got this error messages

> htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given
>   (View:
>   /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/PROJECT/overtek/resources/views/pages/purchaseIndex.blade.php)

this are my controller

```
public function index()
{
  $pa = DB::table('account_pay_ables')
                ->whereNull('invoice')
                ->get();
  return view('pages.purchaseIndex',['pa'=>$pa]);
}
```

i've tried this one too same result

```
$pa = DB::select("SELECT count(*) as new FROM account_pay_ables  WHERE invoice IS NULL");
```

currently on my purchaseIndex.blade.php just this

```
@foreach($pa as $data)
  {{ $data}}
@endforeach
```

Comment: Could you add a dd($pa) beneath your db query and post the result?

Comment: MD.Sukel Ali answer worked thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```php
@foreach($pa as $data)
  {{ optional($data)->new }}
@endforeach
```

Optional function is a good wrapper for this, if an object is null, anything you access from it is null , else it outputs as normal.

BUT, I suppose `$data` is an object, so you need to either transform it into a string, or put it into HTML, so do that first.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is not in your whereNull() method. Problem is in your view.

```
@foreach($pa as $data)
  {{ $data->column_name }} // you can't print an object instead print a string 
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

In fact, your code in Controller is right, the problem is in the view.
Next time you can check the problem step by step.
For example, you can stop the request by adding this

```
dump($pa);
```

and you can see if the data is right.
If your data from DB is right, you will focus on your view code.
I hope that will make sence.